# Vue 3 grid not working any more, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: vue.js, css-grid, vuejs3

This question was first asked on vuejs forum but didn't receive an answer (I know it's holidays seasons :)

I’m driving nuts with grids in vue3. It used to work some weeks ago but after some changes in the versions of the packages, I can’t get it working anymore (not sure it’s linked though). I created a small reproducer:

**Package.json** contains:

```
 {
      "name": "test",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "vue": "3.2.26",
        "vue-class-component": "8.0.0-rc.1",
        "vue-router": "4.0.12",
        "primeflex": "^3.1.0",
        "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
        "primevue": "^3.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "17.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-service": "4.5.15",
        "typescript": "4.5.4"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
      ]
    }
```

**src/main.ts** contains:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import MyApp from "./App.vue";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import "primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
import "primevue/resources/primevue.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import "primeflex/primeflex.min.css";

createApp(MyApp)
  .use(PrimeVue)
  .mount("#app");
```

and **src/App.vue** contains basically a copy of the example named “Vertical Layout with Grid” using the vuue 3 syntax with vue-class-component:

```
<template>
  <h2>test</h2>
  <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">
    <div class="p-field p-col">
      <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
      <InputText id="firstname" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-field p-col">
      <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
      <InputText id="lastname" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import InputText from "primevue/inputtext";

@Options({
  components: {
    InputText,
  },
})
export default class MyApp extends Vue {}
</script>
```

This should display something like this:
[image: expected result]
But it actually shows (using Firefox):
[image: actual result]
and I’m totally unable to get both fields side by side…
Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44P2h.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nZk.png

Comment: Try using the [Firefox Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector) to check what are the CSS property applyed on `<div class="p-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">` maybe some CSS filed aren't loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

@BenSouchet Thanks for your comment, you pushed me to the right track.

Precisely, I first looked only at p-fluid which I was able to find in the CSS but after your comment I looked closer and I found I was unable to find p-formgrid, p-grid, or p-field in the page nor in the node_modules directory.

Running `grep -R 'p-grid' node_modules/prime*` does not return anything...

So, I looked twice at https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/migration and discovered that with primeflex 3, all classes named p-xxx are now named xxx (eg p-formgrid becomes formgrid) so I changed the classes in the template above and it's now working fine again...

Now, the next question is why such a breaking change???  I need to pass through my whole application to fix that :/